# Google Calendar API: get list of free slots on specified day

Tags: javascript, npm, google-calendar-api

I need to get list of free slots in my google calendar. Now I am just getting list of events. I am using [google calendar](https://www.npmjs.com/package/google-calendar) npm.

```
google_calendar.events.list(calObj.name,{
    timeMin: "2018-03-02T08:00:00.000Z",
    timeMax: "2018-03-02T16:00:00.000Z",
    singleEvents: true,
    orderBy: "startTime"
}, function (err, eventList) {
    // handle to get output like
    // freeSlots -> [{
    //     "startDate": "2018-03-02T08:00:00.000Z",
    //     "endDate": "2018-03-02T09:00:00.000Z"
    // },{
    //     "startDate": "2018-03-02T07:00:00.000Z",
    //     "endDate": "2018-03-02T08:00:00.000Z"
    // }]

    // if at this day are events between 10:00 and 16:00 (so calendar is busy)
})
```

Comment: AFAIK, there is no API endpoint to get a list of free slots on a specific day. A work around would be is to getting the list of events for the day then arrange it from the beginning of the day to the end. Calculate the time in between the event. Then there you have the free slot on that specific day. Hope this helps.

Comment: first you'd have to define "slot". The calendar does not have fixed "slots". An event can be as long or short as you like, and start / finish at any time you like, so your question does not really make sense.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can get free slots from google calendar in two steps. Using [npm google-calendar](https://www.npmjs.com/package/google-calendar)

1st you have to get all free/busy times in your calendar

```
var startDate = new Date(),
    endDate = new Date();

var rootStart = startDate,
    rootEnd = endDate;

gcal(<accessToken>).freebusy.query({
    "items":[{
        "id": calObj.name
    }],
    "timeMin": startDate.toISOString(),
    "timeMax": endDate.toISOString(),
    "timeZone": "GMT+0100"
},{
    fields: "calendars,groups,kind,timeMax,timeMin", 
    alt:"json"
}, function(err, data) {
    if(err) return console.log(err)

    // then calculate free slots
    return slotsFromEvents(startDate, data.calendars[<calName>].busy)
})

var interval = 2, // how big single slot should be (in this case 2 hrs) 
freeSlots = []; 

function slotsFromEvents(date,events) {
    events.forEach(function (event, index) { //calculate free from busy times
        if (index == 0 && startDate < event.start) {
            freeSlots.push({startDate: startDate, endDate: event.start});
        }
        else if (index == 0) {
            startDate = event.end;
        }
        else if (events[index - 1].end < event.start) {
            freeSlots.push({startDate: events[index - 1].end, endDate: event.start});
        }

        if (events.length == (index + 1) && event.end < endDate) {
            freeSlots.push({startDate: event.end, endDate: endDate});
        }
    });


    if (events.length == 0) {
        freeSlots.push({startDate: startDate, endDate: endDate});
    }

    var temp = {}, hourSlots = [];
    freeSlots.forEach(function(free, index) {
        var freeHours = new Date(free.endDate).getHours() - new Date(free.startDate).getHours(), freeStart = new Date(free.startDate), freeEnd = new Date(free.endDate);
        while(freeStart.getHours()+freeHours+interval>=0) { // 11 + 4 + 2 >= 0
            if(freeHours>=interval) {
                temp.e = new Date(free.startDate);
                temp.e.setHours(temp.e.getHours()+freeHours);
                temp.s = new Date(free.startDate);
                temp.s.setHours(temp.s.getHours()+freeHours-interval);
                if(temp.s.getHours() >= rootStart.getHours() && temp.e.getHours() <= rootEnd.getHours()) {
                    hourSlots.push({calName: calObj.name, startDate:temp.s, endDate:temp.e});
                    temp = {};
                }
            }
            freeHours--;
        }
    })

    // callBack(freeSlots, hourSlots);
}
```

Comment: Hello. Can be this easily transformed in a sort of calendar that can be shared with other people (something like 'my free time slots')?