# How can I take the Google Calendar free slots list for the current date using Android Studio?

Tags: android, android-studio, google-calendar-api, android-googleapiclient

I take the `Event` list from the Android developer tutorial like this:

```
  private List<String> getDataFromApi() throws IOException {
        // List the next 10 events from the primary calendar.
        DateTime now = new DateTime(System.currentTimeMillis());
        List<String> eventStrings = new ArrayList<String>();
        List<String> tests = new ArrayList<String>();

        Events events = mService.events().list("primary")
                .setMaxResults(10)
                .setTimeMin(now)
                .setOrderBy("startTime")
                .setSingleEvents(true)
                .execute();


        List<Event> items = events.getItems();

        for (Event event : items) {
            DateTime start = event.getStart().getDateTime();

            if (start == null) {
                // All-day events don't have start times, so just use
                // the start date.
                start = event.getStart().getDate();
            }
            eventStrings.add(
                    String.format("%s (%s) test", event.getSummary(), start));
        }

        return eventStrings;
    }
```

And also, the following post has a similar question:

[Google Calendar API: get list of free slots on specified day](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49073994/google-calendar-api-get-list-of-free-slots-on-specified-day).

But I am stuck on how to convert that answer to Android Studio (Java).

Please guide me on how to do this - thank you.

Comment: Which DateTime are you using?

Comment: using Joda library?

Comment: import com.google.api.client.util.DateTime;

Comment: See the answer. you may still need to change something about the data conversions but from logic perspective that is the hard translation of that JS code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Considering `DateTime` is `org.joda.time.DateTime` from Joda library, it would roughly translate to this -

N.B: DateTime comparisons would depend on your used class, so most likely you will need to change those. Don't blindly copy-paste

```
class MyEvent implements  Comparable<MyEvent>{
        public DateTime startDate; // org.joda.time.DateTime
        public DateTime endDate; // org.joda.time.DateTime

        public MyEvent(DateTime startDate, DateTime endDate) {
            this.startDate = startDate;
            this.endDate = endDate;
        }
        /**
         *
         * @param  anotherEvent
         * @return 0 for same time, 1 : this>anotherEvent, -1 : this<anotherEvent
         */
        @Override
        public int compareTo(@NonNull MyEvent anotherEvent) {
            // implement 0/1/-1 based on your DateTime object

            return 0;
        }
    }


    private void calender(){

        // List the next 10 events from the primary calendar.
        DateTime startDate = new DateTime(System.currentTimeMillis()); // org.joda.time.DateTime
        DateTime endDate  = startDate.plusHours(24); //endData 24 hours from start date

        DateTime rootStart = startDate;
        DateTime rootEnd = endDate;
        List<String> eventStrings = new ArrayList<String>();
        List<String> tests = new ArrayList<String>();

        Events events = mService.events().list("primary")
                .setMaxResults(10)
                .setTimeMax(endDate)
                .setTimeMin(startDate)
                .setOrderBy("startTime")
                .setSingleEvents(true)
                .execute();


        List<Event> items = events.getItems();

        int interval = 2 ; // how big single slot should be (in this case 2 hrs)
        ArrayList<MyEvent> freeSlots = new ArrayList<MyEvent>();
        for (int index =0;index<items.size();index++) {
            Event event = items.get(index);
            DateTime eventStart = event.getStart().getDateTime(); // TODO: create org.joda.time.DateTime obj using the return value of getDateTime()
            DateTime eventEnd = event.getEnd().getDateTime(); // TODO: create org.joda.time.DateTime obj using the return value of getDateTime()

            if (index == 0 && startDate.isBefore(eventStart) ) { 
                freeSlots.add( new MyEvent(startDate,eventStart) );
            }
            else if (index == 0) {
                startDate = event.getEnd().getDateTime(); // TODO: create org.joda.time.DateTime obj using the return value of getDateTime()
            }
            else if (events.get(index - 1).getEnd().getDateTime() /* // TODO: create org.joda.time.DateTime obj using the return value of getDateTime() */.isBefore(eventStart)==-1) {
                freeSlots.add(new MyEvent(items.get(index - 1).getEnd().getDateTime() /* // TODO: create org.joda.time.DateTime obj using the return value of getDateTime() */,eventStart));
            }

            if (items.size() == (index + 1) && event.getEnd().getDateTime().isBefore(endDate)) {
                freeSlots.add(new MyEvent(eventEnd, endDate));
            }
        }
        if (items.size() == 0) {
            freeSlots.add(new MyEvent(startDate,endDate));
        }

        ArrayList<MyEvent> hourSlots = new ArrayList<MyEvent>();
        MyEvent temp = null;
        for(int index =0;index<freeSlots.size();index++){
            MyEvent free = (MyEvent) freeSlots.get(index);

            int freeHours = free.endDate.getHourOfDay()- free.startDate.getHourOfDay();
            DateTime freeStart = free.startDate, freeEnd = free.endDate;
            while(freeStart.getHourOfDay()+freeHours+interval>=0) { // 11 + 4 + 2 >= 0
                if(freeHours>=interval) {
                    temp.startDate = free.startDate;
                    temp.endDate= temp.endDate.hourOfDay().setCopy(temp.endDate.getHourOfDay()+freeHours);
                    temp.startDate = free.startDate;
                    temp.startDate = temp.startDate.hourOfDay().setCopy(temp.startDate.getHourOfDay()+freeHours-interval);
                    if(temp.startDate.getHourOfDay() >= rootStart.getHourOfDay() && temp.endDate.getHourOfDay() <= rootEnd.getHourOfDay()) {
                        hourSlots.add(new MyEvent(temp.startDate,temp.endDate));
                        temp = null;
                    }
                }
                freeHours--;
            }
        }
    }
```

In your `build.gradle` add -

```
implementation 'joda-time:joda-time:2.10'
```

Comment: Sir, joda library not support for .setTimeMin(startDate) it's required import com.google.api.client.util.DateTime

Comment: So do the conversion by yourself.

Comment: events.get(index - 1).getEnd().getDateTime() in here "getEnd" cannot resolve method, why is that?